# How to make corners rounded in electron app

Tags: html, css, node.js, electron

```
const electron = require("electron");
const {app, BrowserWindow, globalShortcut} = electron;
const path = require("path");

function createWindow(){
    win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1000, 
        height: 750, 
        icon: path.join(__dirname,'\checked.png'),
        frame: false,
        fullscreenable:false,
        // radii: [5,5,5,5],
        // transparent:true

    });

    win.loadFile('mainWindow.html')
    win.setMenu(null);
}
```

Always has a white border gap on corners, making it rectangular.

Have attempted to increase border size of css but everything expands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crucial properties for this are: `frame: false` and `transparent: true` (you missed the latter)

*js*

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
const path = require('path')

app.once('ready', () => {
  let win = new BrowserWindow({
    frame: false,
    transparent: true
  })
  win.loadURL(path.join(__dirname, '/roundedcorner.html'))
})
```

*html*

```
<html>
  <body>
      <p style="border-radius: 25px; background: #73AD21; height: 300px;"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you use 'transparent' background on body? (like it is as default in my example) `transparent: true` only _allows_ your html to be really transparent.

Comment: Also, can I just ask why when i put fullscreenable:false, its still able to open as a full screen

Comment: @HarF-kingNeat idk what do u mean by "its still able to open as a full screen". I had no problem with it so far. It disables `win.setFullScreen` call properly. With some more detail you can open a new question! ;)